# JavaScript: Get Function calling HTML-Object

Tags: javascript, events, function

Hey,
yes, I know that with `[funcname].caller` or `arguments.callee.caller` you can get a reference to the function which called the actual function, BUT - the following scenario:

`<a href="#" onclick="return something()">Test</a>`

Inside of `something()` I have no chance to get to the A-Tag, even with the `.caller` reference, unless I alter the script in the following way:

`<a href="#" onclick="return something(this)">Test</a>`

With "this" I'm passing my A-Tag reference to the function but is there a way to get the A-Tag reference without explicitly passing it to the function?

Comment: what exactly you want to accomplish? If you want a link from javascript why not use window.navigate?

Comment: I want to perform an action after clicking on the A-Tag (or let it be an input:button) and alter the calling object. Lets say I want to change the Link/Button-Text to "Please wait".

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this is doing fine, it's just one word of code and it doesn't harm.Using jquery you can do this way

```
$(function(){
    $("body").delegate("a", "click", function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

//Both code will work for you

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(
        function(){
            alert($(this).html());
        }
    );
})
```

Comment: This way I would observe all A-Tags in my document, even if they don't call my somefunction() in an onclick event. And what if the user wants to use the function with an input:button? I don't think thats the right solution.

Comment: @Christian in that case use 'input[type=button]' instead of 'a', there are lot's of alternatives in jquery!!

Comment: @Christian besides you can filter `a` tags by putting classes `$('a.classname')` as well as by id `$('a#id')` or other various attributes `$('a[name=somename]')`

Comment: Yeah, sure - but this way I have to observe a million eventualities... Take look at my alternative idea in Alisey's post.

Comment: @Christian Engel Well have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055228/defining-javascript-event-object and http://www.webdevelopersjournal.com/articles/jsevents3/jsevents3.html and sure you will find jquery or passing `this` as an argument is more advisable. and about your alternative, sure you can do this better with passing `this` on function and integer as other parameter. But still i am not sure if i fully comprehend your question.