# Defining JavaScript Event Object

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting an error for this piece of code?:

```
function catchevent() 
{
    eventSrcID=(event.srcElement)?event.srcElement.id:'undefined';

    eventtype=event.type;

    status=eventSrcID+' has received a '+eventtype+' event.';
}
```

Firefox says that `event` is not defined. Actually, this is copied from [here](http://www.webdevelopersjournal.com/articles/jsevents3/jsevents3.html) and it clearly says that it is for IE5.  I use Firefox 3.6.13 on Ubuntu.

My Question is not why it doesn't work on my browser.  Instead, is there a way to define `event` object, as suggested by the link, that would work for my browser?

**UPDATE**

Why isn't this working

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function catchevent( e ) {
      // reference the proper event object
    var e = e || window.event;

      // reference the proper target
    var srcElem = e.target || e.srcElement; //line no 9

      // get the id of the target
    var eventSrcID = srcElem.id;

    alert(eventSrcID);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="link1" href="#" onclick="catchevent()">link1</a>
    <a id="link2" href="#" onclick="catchevent()">link2</a>
    <a id="link3" href="#" onclick="catchevent()">link3</a>

</body>
</html>
```

For this i am still getting error on line no 9

```
e is undefined
[Break On This Error] var srcElem = e.target || e.srcElement;
```

Now how do I need to pass `event` object on `catchevent()` or is there some mistake? please suggest.

Comment: I might suggest to use a guide less focused on an ancient browser with historically awful standards support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Firefox and other W3C compliant browsers, the handler function will receive an event object as an argument to the function.

IE uses a global `event` object.

Here's a cross browser solution for your code.

```
function catchevent( e ) {
      // reference the proper event object
    var e = e || window.event;

      // reference the proper target
    var srcElem = e.target || e.srcElement;

      // get the id of the target
    var eventSrcID = srcElem.id;

      // get the event type
    var eventtype = e.type;

      // create the status string
    var status = eventSrcID + ' has received a ' + eventtype + ' event.';
}
```

You'll notice I used the `var` keyword when creating variables. You should do this, otherwise you're creating global variables.

Also note that the keyword `this` will be a reference to the element to which the handler was assigned.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. For more info, see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Comment: I tried your code and I am getting some error. please would you have a look at updates

Comment: @experimentX: This is because you're using the inline `onclick`. Since W3C browsers don't have a global event object, you need to make sure it gets passed. Try changing your inline handlers to this: `onclick="catchevent.call(this,event)"` I haven't tested this on all browsers, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 4):

you forgot to pass event in parameters.

```
function catchevent(event) 
{
    eventSrcID=(event.srcElement)?event.srcElement.id:'undefined';

    eventtype=event.type;

    status=eventSrcID+' has received a '+eventtype+' event.';
}
```

Comment: This may not be possible. For example, `document.getElementById('foo').click = catchevent;` - It would be up to the browser whether it gets passed, and this depends on which browser you're in.

Comment: i guess you are right, but i assumed FF because experimentX said he used Firefox 3.6.13 on Ubuntu.

Comment: anyway everyone was helpful, would you have a look at my updated code please

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, the first param passed to a handler is the event. So a cross browser piece of code would check for a param and use it if present. If not present, it would default to window.event, the IE way.

Answer (score 1):

The event object is a global variable in internet explorer. (Actually a property of the global window variable)

Firefox is simply a different design, and event is not a global variable in firefox. Instead, it is passed into the function (so you would need to change catchEvent() to accept a parameter:

```
function catchEvent(event){
```

Take a look at this artice because that is not the only problem you'll face with the event model:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html[Quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)