# event.srcElement in firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I have some old code that I'm updating to work in firefox, and I've run across a problem.

In the code, there's a function that looks like this:

```
function tableEnter() {

     myLocation = event.srcElement;

}
```

This doesn't work in firefox. I've researched this quite a bit, but most of the solutions I've found require an event to be passed to this function, and then act on the e parameter that was passed. ...Unfortunately in the code that I'm updating, I'm not getting any parameters passed.

What's the solution to making the event.srcElemet work in firefox, without any parameters being passed to my function?

Edit:

Okay, the question is becoming: How do i pass the event object to my tableEnter() function?

Here's what the code is currently doing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //make table rows
    //for every new table row...
    myRow.onmouseover = tableEnter; (this is probably a bad name. it should be like..rowEnter. But this is the way I found the code)
});
```

the question is now, how do i pass the event object into tableEnter() so that I can do the things suggested on the internet, and the answers below.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055228/defining-javascript-event-object & note you also need to capture the event object itself differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly can't see why you would want to have access to the event object, without it being an argument of your handler. But, hey, that's just me. Although no parameters are specified, FF and chrome just do as they please and pass the event object to the handler anyway. So:

```
function tableEnter()
{
    var evt = window.event || arguments[0];
    var src = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
}
```

And that's it. Personally, I would advise you to do what the whole wide web is doing:

```
function handler(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
}
```

Since you're using FF, you shouldn't try to diverge from any of the coding conventions or standards too much, however vague they might be. At least it's better than no standards or conventions *at all*.

---

In view of your update, just change your function definition to:

```
function tableEnter(e)
{
    //though in jQuery, I suspect e is allready X-browser-proof
    e = e || window.event;
    //just leave ^^this^^ line out, and check in IE: alert(typeof e);
    //if it alerts object, jQuery passed the event object for you
    var theRow = this;//<-- this points to the row that triggered the mouseover
    var jQRow = $(this);//gives you access to jQuery methods

    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;//<-- mainly of importance in delegation
}
```

Comment: added clarity to the question above. I'd like to implement your (second) solution. I just need guided in the right direction.

Comment: @1__: I updated my answer, some more explanation in comments, too